# Vue.js return undefined data after CORS consult in hug server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hug

I want to get data from localhost API from hug server to vue client.
I have this code in vue.js:

```
        <div id="aplicacio">
        {{ documents }}
        <ul>
            <li v-for="document in documents">
                <a v-bind:href="document.path">{{ document.title }}</a>: {{document.text}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    <script>
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#aplicacio',
                data: {
                    documents: []
                },
                created () {
                    fetch('http://localhost:8000/documents/list')
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json => {
                            this.documents = json.documents
                        })
                }
            })
    </script>
```

and this code in hug:

```
import hug
api = hug.API(__name__)
api.http.add_middleware(hug.middleware.CORSMiddleware(api, max_age=100))


@hug.get('/documents/list')
def list():
    """Returns list of documents"""
    j = [{"text": "Hola", "path": "normativa.md", "title": "Normativa"}, {"text": "Això és una *activitat*", "path": "activitat1.md", "title": "Activitat 1"}]
    return j
```

Misteriously when I consult `applicacio.documents` in firefox console, it gets me `undefined`. It is not CORS problem, because I add `api.http.add_middleware(hug.middleware.CORSMiddleware(api, max_age=100))` in the backend and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="" />` in the web page.

Comment: but your json does not seem to be ```{"documents":[{"text":"Hola"}...]}``` ... but directly the array, no? if you have firefox, just look at the network calls and observe your response data

Comment: what do you see in the console if you `console.log(json.documents)` just after `this.documents = json.documents` ?

Comment: @Bravo: `undefined`

Comment: @user753642 Thank you very much. Yes, it miss `{'documents'...}`. I thought vue.js gets any JSON data and assigns to `documents` data in my application. Thanks. This solves my problem. Can you put a answer and I give you the points?

Comment: so have I @somenxavier . It is not related to Vue but to fetch. Should you use axios, you would have to get the json from the data property of the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check your api response.

Especially if it has the property "documents" in its json payload.

```
.then(json => {
  // are we sure json includes a property documents?
  // maybe json is the array itself
  console.log(json) 
  this.documents = json.documents
})
```

Comment: Be aware your json includes a `documents` key.